# System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException,System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have a project in mvc its rewriting  in code first  the project was work on visual studio 2012  and sql server 2012
now i try to run this on visual studio 2015 and sql 2014 and that throw  exception : of type 'System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code'

model:

```
public class DataBase: DbContext 
{     
    public DbSet<Branch> Branch { get; set; }              
}
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View(db.Branch.ToList());//Here the exception is thrown
    }
```

web-config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-try1-20170718120936.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-try1-20170718120936;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="DataBase" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Fitness-20170115203941;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Fitness-20170115203941.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

`

Comment: Is there an InnerException with more detail?

Comment: the : An exception of type 'System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

Comment: _ensure that the connection string is correct_ - so.. are they correct? Do they work in Sql Server Management Studio?